# How to apply conditional formatting to color partial text string?

Tags: excel, vba, string, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to adjust the Excel VBA code to find and color a specific part of the text string found?

I am using the following code to find and highlight all cells with text string "@gmail.com" and "@yahoo.com" in column V. The text string in column V is like this:

> BBC43555;johnsmith@gmail.com;77888857778;phone:0018888889

It cannot be divided into columns because it may contain different number and order of information fields combined in it.

I would like to highlight only the specific text string found. I would appreciate a simple solution with a good explanation, since I am just starting to collect experience with VBA.

```
Columns("V").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="@gmail.com", _
    TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16752384
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13421823
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="@yahoo.com", _
    TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16752384
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13421823
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Comment: This is what I found with quick search, it sounds like exactly what you need: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3775-excel-highlight-part-of-text-in-cell.html

Comment: You cannot do this with conditional formatting. It requires a text string in the cell (**NOT** a formula that returns a string), and you need to use the `.Characters` property of the `Range` object to do this.  Suggest that you record a macro doing this manually and examine the results.  To do this on multiple cells, you will need to search each cell for the substring(s), and, if found, apply the formatting to the specific characters in that cell.

Comment: @M.Douda - thank you, but the provided solution highlights just the part of the string that is entered in a promt box. I am looking for a 'fixed' solution that would mark all the defined keywords and parts of the string, which also means that there might be several highlighted elements in one string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on data in column 1, with text (no formulas):

```
Sub test()

Dim CL As Range
Dim POS As Long, Before As Long, After As Long

For Each CL In Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
    POS = 0
    If InStr(1, CL.Text, "@gmail.com") > 0 Then POS = InStr(1, CL.Text, "@gmail.com")
    If InStr(1, CL.Text, "@yahoo.com") > 0 Then POS = InStr(1, CL.Text, "@yahoo.com")
    If POS > 0 Then
        Before = InStrRev(CL.Text, ";", POS)
        After = InStr(POS, CL.Text, ";")
        With CL.Characters(Start:=Before + 1, Length:=After - (Before + 1)).Font
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
        End With
    End If
Next CL

End Sub
```

Maybe not the most elegant and waterproof solution....

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the string is like: "BBC43555;johnsmith@gmail.com;adamsmith@yahoo.com;77888857778;phone:0018888889" In this case just the last element will be highlighted...
I would like all the important string parts of the same cell to be highlighted. Sometimes it is just one, sometimes more than three. And not always the elements are divided by  ";". For example, I would like to make light-grey the unimportant parts of the string like "phone:"