# Excel VBA - formatting of inconsistent text strings

Tags: excel, vba, string, string-formatting, conditional-formatting

It seems to be a huge challenge for Excel VBA to format inconsistent text strings and so I am looking for a solution to format the following table:

[image: table without formatting]

The table may contain hundreads of rows that have to be manually checked and so it is important to make it as readable as possible. Unfortunately, the column C contains a very long and messy text string that is inconsistent and cannot be changed since it is being imported from another system.

**Therefore I would like to do the following:**

- make all the unimportant parts of the text string in column C
  light-grey highlight rows (cells in columns A:C)
- if *'the_good_indicator'* is found in column C highlight specific cells with certain string elements in them (e.g. phone    number
  *'00111222333'*)

**The table should look like this:**
[image: desired look of the table]

I have done some research and found partial answers in:

- [StackOverflow discussion "Excel VBA - how to apply conditional formatting to color partial text string?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653276/excel-vba-how-to-apply-conditional-formatting-to-color-partial-text-string) - the solution suggested here does not work with inconsistent text strings.
- [Stack OverFlow discussion "Formatting List of Text Strings in Excel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708050/formatting-list-of-text-strings-in-excel?rq=1) - this method does not work without a reference list.
- [Suggested post "How to highlight specific text within a cell based on other text?"](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3775-excel-highlight-part-of-text-in-cell.html) - this method does not work with a fixed list of keywords without a promt box.

**Still the best I can get is table like this:**
[image: table with current formatting]

...which I get by using the code:

```
Columns("C").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="the_good_indicator", _
    TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16752384
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ColorIndex = 43
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="00111222333", _
    TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16752384
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13561798
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

I will appreciate any help or ideas how to do formatting for such inconsistent text strings.

Comment: Issue is, how do you intend on defining what is a good string and what isn't? Computer doesn't have speech pattern recognition like we do, to the computer, English language is alien (sorta). It's **impossible to provide an answer to your question, unless you provide a list of these good indicator keywords and their format** - eg. `PhoneNumber: #########;` etc and also if `;` is always the denominator

Comment: @Rawrplus - the list of good indicator keywords might be quite long, but in this example it is just "the_good_indicator" and "00111222333" for background color and ";Names=", "PhoneNumber=", ";mobilePhoneNumber=", ";something_unimportant=YES". So, denominators are `;` and `=` I guess.

Comment: What is the problem?  You have a list of keywords and you have your delimiters. A routine to find them in your text string (using either `INSTR` or `Regular Expressions` should be pretty straightforward.  Then just use the `.Characters` property of the `Range` object to do the formatting.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld - sounds easy. Can you, please, suggest some good source of information for applying `INSTR` and `Regular Expressions`? I mean, entry-level source for those with little Excel-VBA experience. Thank you!

Comment: Not at my computer now but you can search stackoverflow for using regular expressions in VBA and you can examine VBA help on the msdn for information about `Instr`